# Quotes problem in Mavericks (or TextEdit)

Tags: macos, textedit

TextEdit in Mavericks changes the standard double quotes `"Hello"` to using curly, non-ascii quotation marks `“Hello”`.  It does this even when you edit plain text documents.  Is there a way to prevent this new behavior in Mavericks?

Comment: If you're looking for a text editor, then TextEdit is the wrong tool, and has many problems and limitations. Something like BBEdit is much more suited to the task.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This is not just TextEdit, it's Mavericks.

Under System Preferences > Keyboard, you can change the quotation marks.

Go to the 'Text' sub-menu.  On the right-hand side of the box, uncheck the "Use smart quotes and dashes" checkbox.

Comment: For those that still can't find it, more specifically: System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Uncheck the "Use smart quotes and dashes" checkbox.

Comment: For the ones which already have a file damaged with this little hanging worms (I mean `‟ ″`), look at the answer from igaar: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/171855/22003 .

Comment: "Smart quotes"? More like... "Dumb quotes".

Comment: @Rob, Are you sure it's the problem with the OS itself? Then why do other apps not have this problem except for Textedit>?

Comment: @Pacerier probably because only mac native apps rely on that behavior. Similar to how mac text autocorrect only works in safari, etc

Comment: What even is the point of "smart quotes" to begin with...

Answer (score 17):

The following procedure worked for me:

In TextEdit select all your text by pressing <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and then go to Edit > Substitutions and uncheck Smart Quotes. Make sure Smart Quotes is not active and it should be solved.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Tragically `Cmd + a` then toggling the setting seems to do nothing to get rid of them.  You have to turn it off then do a normal ` edit menu -> find+replace` to get rid of those smart quotes...after turning them off.

Answer (score 2):

If you already unchecked System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Use smart quotes and dashes.

There's also a checkmark on TextEdit > Preferences > "Smart quotes" (I don't know the translation but it something like that).

Be sure to uncheck that one too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried unchecking the Smart quotes option in both the MAC system preferences `system preferences -> keyboard -> text tab untick the use smart quotes and dashes option` and in textedit app preferences at `textedit -> preferences -> uncheck smart quotes and dashes in rich text documents only option`

But the issue was still not resolved for me. When I type single quote or double quote in rich text document then it is converted to curly quote. For example, if I do a search using `command+F` for the single quote then it will not find any.

The only way I was able to solve this in my MAC is that I need to use `ctrl` key when typing either single quote or double quote. For example, when typing single quote I need to type `ctrl + singlequote` and when typing double quote I need to type `ctrl + shift + doublequote`

I am using MAC OS Catalina and rich text document, hope someone can point to a permanent fix for this rather than remembering the keyboard shortcut each time.

Comment: Did you also check the Edit menu?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that by default, TextEdit (and other apps) inherit from the `preferences -> keyboard` setting.

But they only inherit from it at start time.  So you can change it in `preferences -> keyboard`, then restart you app.

Or if you specify it within the apps `Edit menu -> Substitutions -> Smart quotes` then it appears to override whatever the keyboard preference is (permanently) but for just that app.  So they both work.

Comment: What is you macos version?  It should be included in the answer.

Comment: Catalina, I assume it still applies for others...