# How do I save a text file with a Ruby (.rb) file extension?

Tags: terminal, textedit, ruby

I am new to Ruby and am trying to learn from a book. However, I have one problem – it says I should save a file so that it ends with `.rb` but my Mac only lets me use `.rtf` so that's what I used. But the next thing I needed to do was open it in Terminal and the command `cd /Users/username/ruby` didn't work for me. I'm guessing the reason for this is because I didn't use `.rb` it didn't work.

So my question is: **What should I use for writing Ruby in the end of that command, or for saving with the `.rb` extension?**

Answer (score 5):

You could only save as .rtf because the file was **rich text**. To make it plain text, simply press <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>-<kbd>⌘ command</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> or go **Format** > **Make Plain Text**, then you can save as .rb.

Try not to use TextEdit: there is no syntax highlighting and code completion, not to mention that you have to manually turn off those [wrong quotation marks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/quotes-problem-in-mavericks-or-textedit).

Answer (score 2):

What you do is get yourself a proper code editor or IDE. Using TextEdit to write code is a very bad idea. Personally I'd recommend Sublime Text 3 because it has good text highlighting for many different languages, is free (well technically isn't, but for learning like you're doing, not buying a license should be ok), and is pretty lightweight but you should do some research and reach your own conclusions about which code editor or IDE is right for you.

Comment: TextMate is another possibility: https://macromates.com/download

Answer (score 1):

Could always use good ole `vim YOURFILENAMEHERE.rb` within Terminal.

When you want to type, enter insertion mode by pressing <kbd>i</kbd>; if you want to exit insertion mode, press <kbd>ESC</kbd>. Then to save your file just press <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (save and then quit).

Of course you miss out on all of the IDE features but it's a great text editor that is built in.